# Python help - read txt into list but the code read character by character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am self learning python and I encountered a problem when my code tries reading a list saved in txt:

I have a series of number sets saved in the txt: for example the data in txt is as follow:

[5,26,39]

[7,21,40]
…

I have tried the following 2 codes to read the above txt:

```
data = open(r"201219.txt", 'r')
lines = data.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for i in line:
        print(i)
```

AND

```
with open(r"201219.txt", 'r') as data:
lines = data.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    for i in line:
        print(i)
```

Both of the above codes will print something like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFvXs.jpg)

It seems the code is reading each character instead of a number itself. I can't iterate through the items as it is not what I want.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? Thanks very very much.

Comment: A text file is just a sequence of characters -- it has no internal organization other than lines.  It doesn't know that `26` is supposed to be the number 26; it just sees the character `2`, followed by the character `6`, followed by whatever character is next.  If you have the capability to change how the data is saved, then I think json would be a much better format.

Comment: Basically, you have to read and understand how to strip the delimiters to parse the numbers correctly:  lines = data.readlines();

print(lines);

for line in lines:
    ll = line.lstrip('[').rstrip(']\n').split(',');
    print(ll);

Comment: Guys, thanks for helping me. Those are very helpful

Comment: Ifinally found that i can save the data by using .pkl format which can keep the data structure of the output. problem solved. Thanks!